# VR CameraRig rotation, problem throwing objs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steamvr

I'm creating a VR application in Unity using SteamVR. I have implemented a Snap Rotation Script, so, the user can turn himself in-game without doing it phisicaly.

My hierachy is: [CameraRig] -> (Controller left, Controller right, camera)

Now the problem is: when I'm holding an object and i want to throw it, if i rotated the CameraRig earlier, the object throwed behave strangely. Its direction is out of phase, based on the cumulative rotation of the CameraRig.
If I never rotate the CameraRig, the object throwed behave normally

I'm using FixedJoint component to attach the object to the hand.

How can I fix this?

```
public void Drop() {

    // Null Check
    if (!m_CurrentInteractable){
        return;
    }

    // Apply velocity
    Rigidbody targetBody = m_CurrentInteractable.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    targetBody.velocity = m_pose.GetVelocity();
    targetBody.angularVelocity = m_pose.GetAngularVelocity();

    // Detach
    m_Joint.connectedBody = null;

    // Clear
    m_CurrentInteractable.m_ActiveHand = null;
    m_CurrentInteractable = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating your velocity and angularVelocity, try to add one more step afterwards which incorporates the rig:

```
velocity = Rig.transform.rotation * velocity;
angularVelocity = Rig.transform.rotation * angularVelocity;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I don't understand. What i should do? Because  velocity and angular velocity are both Vector3, and .rotation is a Quaternion. Even if I take the Euler Angle, I can't anyway multiply two vector3

Comment: Sorry, I had meant angularVelocity = Rig.transform.rotation * angularVelocity;, which in Unity is a valid operation (quaternion mulltiplied by vector3, whereas my shortened "*=" apparently isn't allowed) -- give it a try, I'm successfully using that same code in my VR object for throwing objects from within rotated rigs. Will edit my answer.

Comment: OK, one more things: What do you mean with Rig? The root of the hierachy or the GameObject Hand?

Comment: In the VR applications I've worked with using SteamVR or Oculus library, there's always a rig playspace representing the roomscale real world wrapper, that's what I mean with Rig. It is the part of the hierarchy you'd want to rotate (e.g. in steps of 45 degrees) even when the player doesn't want to rotate. It is where e.g. the OVR Camera Rig component is attached, or the SteamVR Play Area/ SteamVR Controller Manager (terms may differ in SteamVR2).

Comment: I've tried, but now the interactable obj won't detach from my hand. Maybe if i show you the Hand Controller script, it will helps

Comment: nope, everything is fine. I bet is due to hand controller script